# Extract all transaction that contains specific item/items

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I would like to extract from Redshift using SQL for transactions that contain certain items. I have two tables (one for items and one for transaction with customer ids)

Item table
| Item |
| ---- |
|Apple |
|Pencil|
|Paper |

| Customer id | Transaction id | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | Apple |
| 1 | a | Pencil |
| 2 | b | Apple |
| 3 | c | Paper |
| 3 | c | Apple |
| 3 | e | Pencil |
| 4 | f | Apple |
| 5 | g | Apple |
| 5 | g | Paper |
|  | h | Apple |
|  | h | Paper |
|  | i | Pencil |
|  | j | Paper |

How to extract all transactions containing Apple?

I'm expecting to get this result

| Customer id | Transaction id | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | Apple |
| 1 | a | Pencil |
| 2 | b | Apple |
| 3 | c | Paper |
| 3 | c | Apple |
| 4 | f | Apple |
| 5 | g | Apple |
| 5 | g | Paper |
|  | h | Apple |
|  | h | Paper |

Comment: Nope.  Invalid edit, and you may only ask for one query at a time.  Please limit your question to one query only.  Currently, your question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

We can try using `COUNT()` as an analytic function here to count the number of times the apple item occurs for each group of transactions.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(CASE WHEN Item = 'Apple' THEN 1 END) OVER
                  (PARTITION BY TransactionId) cnt
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT CustomerId, TransactionId, Item
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 0
ORDER BY TransactionId, Item;
```

Comment: Do you mean CASE WHEN Item IN ('Apple','Orange')...?

Comment: @Ameer My answer requires a transaction only to have apples.  If you have some other logic, then edit your question.

Comment: Sorry. I should've written my question properly. 2nd situation is what about if I want to have all transactions that MUST contain Apple AND Pencil

Comment: I have changed my questions

Comment: Question 3. Apple OR Pencil. Can I write like this?  COUNT(CASE WHEN Item IN ('Apple','Pencil') THEN 1 END)

Comment: Since your original question has been answered, you should accept the answer. Open a new question if you need further assistance.